# Linux access MSSQL failed

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

My Java application in Linux was trying to access an MSSQL database and failed. Keytab, security login, and krb5 all are defined. driver is `sqljdbc4-2.0.jar`. The error message still looking for Windows Authentication.

```
driver:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
url:jdbc:sqlserver://AAA.com:10501;instanceName=BBB_DEV;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
Nov 25, 2016 3:42:26 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll
```

Comment: why devote ? any solution ?

Comment: Your connection string says it all, if not anything else - `integratedSecurity=true` is used for Windows Authentication on SQL Server.

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer No it isn't with recent JDBC drivers, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for that @MarkRotteveel, learnt something new today!

Answer (score 2):

Version 2.0 of the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver is pretty old, support for pure Java Kerberos authentication was only added in version 4.0. See [Using Kerberos Integrated Authentication to Connect to SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122(v=sql.110).aspx):

> Beginning in Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server, an application can use the authenticationScheme connection property to indicate that it wants to connect to a database using Kerberos integrated authentication using the pure Java Kerberos implementation

Either [download version 6.0 from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774), or get version 6.1 from maven using

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```